# Loggin multiple discord bots

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, unique, hosting

> I am trying from 3 days and always failed to create a multiple token login script, basically my idea was to have 1 python script to run & put tokens in **tokens.txt** and whenever you run the project it logins the bot tokens from tokens.txt
>
> For example : we put 5 tokens in .txt and on running it logins all the five bot tokens and prints ( Connected : Username ) in console .....

Pls pls pls someone help me its kind of a project i believe can be done & have also asked to so many devs and they have said it can be surely done but not sure what to exactly do! I would be so thankful if someone can help ...

Comment: Firstly, no you cannot. Secondly why would you want to do that? If you have made 5 bots from discord developer portal then why not code the in different code spaces?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run that many bots at 1 time.

It will only run 1 if you even try to. And when you exit out that one it moves to another one leaving the rest offline.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating your own event loop so you can login multiple instances at the same time.

```py
import asyncio, discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN1 = ""
TOKEN2 = ""

client1 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
client2 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')


loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.create_task(client1.start('TOKEN1'))
loop.create_task(client2.start('TOKEN2'))
loop.run_forever()
```

**References:**
[Similar Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734897/discord-py-run-2-instances-of-a-bot-in-one-script/63740848#63740848),
[Asyncio: Event Loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html)