# Trying to code a Discord selfbot to send message from multiple accounts controlled by one master account

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Hey so ive been trying to make a selfbot and hopefully slowly learn python along the way. I ve gotten far enough to do it in one account but i want to do it from multiple accounts controlled by a master account with commands and command prefixes. This video shows what i am trying to replicate, just i want to do it in server as well and not necessarily spam that much just one set of message from each account is good enough. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1N6cR-FIJgE This is the video. How do i convert the code to use multiple tokens and control those accounts with a master account. https://github.com/casrfgd2/discod - this is the code

Comment: This is a question and answer site, not a general solicitation for help site. If you have a specific question, please edit this to ask it.

Comment: Selfbots are against Discord's [terms of service](https://discord.com/terms).

Comment: @zephyr I have done so

Comment: Please don't tag both `python` and `node.js`, use only relevant tags - find which lang8iage you're looking to use and edit the tags accordingly.

Comment: Try this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734897/discord-py-run-2-instances-of-a-bot-in-one-script/63740848#63740848

Answer (score -1):

Self bots are against Discord's [Terms of service](https://discord.com/terms) and can get your account or in this case multiple accounts banned

What you could do is make a [discord bot](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and use it to the mass dm (which is also kind of against the terms) with just one discord account

To use multiple bots with the same code you could fork the repository per bot and put the different token in your env file every fork

Comment: Any kind of automated spam in Discord is against the terms of service.